# Pandas csv reader - how to force a column to be a specific data type (and replace NaN with null)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am just getting started with Pandas and I am reading a csv file using the read_csv() method. The difficulty I am having is needing to set a column to a specific data type.

`df = pd.read_csv('test_data.csv', delimiter=',', index_col=False)`

my df looks like this:

```
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------           --------------  -----  
 0   product_code     4 non-null      object 
 1   store_code       4 non-null      int64  
 2   cost1            4 non-null      float64
 3   start_date       4 non-null      int64  
 4   end_date         4 non-null      int64  
 5   quote_reference  0 non-null      float64
 6   min1             4 non-null      int64  
 7   cost2            2 non-null      float64
 8   min2             2 non-null      float64
 9   cost3            1 non-null      float64
 10  min3             1 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(6), int64(4), object(1)
memory usage: 480.0+ bytes
```

you can see that I have multiple 'min' columns min1, min2, min3
min1 is correctly detected as an int64, but min2 and min3 are float64.
this is due to min1 being fully populated, whereas min2, and min3 are sparsely populated.

here is my df:
[image]

as you can see min2 has 2 NaN values.

trying to change the data type using

`df['min2'] = df['min2'].astype('int')`

I get this error:

`IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer`

Ideally I want to change the data type to Int, and have NaN replaced by a NULL (ie don't want a 0).
I have tried a variety of methods, ie fillna, but can't crack this.

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no NULL in Python. Did you mean `None`? In that case, since `None` is not an integer the conversion that you want is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since pandas 1.0, you can use a generic `pandas.NA` to replace `numpy.nan`. This is useful to serve as an [integer NA](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

To perform the convertion, use the `"Int64"` type (note the capital I).

```
df['min2'] = df['min2'].astype('Int64')
```

Example:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, None, 3])
s.astype('Int64')
```

Or:

```
pd.Series([1, 2, None, 3], dtype='Int64')
```

Output:

```
0       1
1       2
2    <NA>
3       3
dtype: Int64
```

Comment: @WJ.Lesster this is a *relatively* new feature. I wish it would be default on many operations ;)